# Iterate Over Web API Pages With Power Query

Tags: json, excel, api, loops, powerquery

I need a little help, please. I have access to API data:
[image]

I'm using the following code to retrieve API data:

```
let iterations = 10,
```

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/[ACCOUNT ID]/insights?access_token=[ACCESS TOKEN]",

```
FnGetOnePage =
  (url) as record =>
   let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url)),
    data = try Source[data] otherwise null,
    next = try Source[paging][next] otherwise null,
    res = [Data=data, Next=next]
   in
    res,

 GeneratedList =
  List.Generate(
   ()=>[i=0, res = FnGetOnePage(url)],
   each [i]<iterations and [res][Data]<>null,
   each [i=[i]+1, res = FnGetOnePage([res][Next])],
   each [res][Data])
 in
  GeneratedList
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve this API data:
[image]

What changes do I need to make to the original code for this?

Any help, suggestion or guidance is much appreciated!

Many thanks,
Tanim

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by copy and pasting the last line from the new API data, it basically got rid of the extra "client_pages" bit and working like a charm. Looks like self help is the best help!

[image]